# How is RedShift's sortkey different from Clustered Index?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

RedShift has a tool called the `sortkey`, a column which you can specify. This will ensure that the data remains in this sorted order.

How is this any different from a clustered index? This does the same thing.

Comment: Yes this is the same thing. Just like the sortkey a clustered index stores data on disk in the same order as the index specified.

Comment: Cool, but why don't they call it a cluster index then?

Comment: Different companies I would imagine.

Comment: sortkey and clustered index are pretty similar in idea, but everything else about indexing goes out the window with columnar databases (like Redshift), so a different name seems warranted.

Comment: The lesson I learned is that the term 'sortkey' is only half right. Yes it defines the order in which the data is stored but for interleaved and compound keys it also enables the block ranges to be stored. So it's half an index and half a sort order.

Answer (score 3):

Amazon Redshift does not support indexes. So, calling it an index would be misleading.

Rather, data is physically stored in the order requested. This has the benefit of enabling **zone maps**, which identify the range of data stored in a given block. For example, if data is sorted by date, each zone map would identify the earliest and latest dates stored in that zone. This helps Redshift ignore blocks that *do not* contain relevant data.

SORTKEYs can also include multiple columns and even [interleaved sorts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/t_Sorting_data-compare-sort-styles.html) -- a method of combining two different sort orders while maintaining efficiency.

Comment: Is there a reason that Redshift doesn't support indexes? Is it because it wouldn't make sense with columnar data stores?

Comment: Redshift is designed to support analytical queries on huge amount of historical data. Indexes can designed for smaller data sets as they double and more the actual data storage. SORT keys might take time to master, and you can't just add them when you want, but they are better cost-effective to these analytical use cases.